# How to hide relevant endpoint based on http method

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger-2.0, spring-boot-actuator, springfox

```
    private Predicate<String> aggregationPaths() {
        return or(regex("/aggregationservice.*"),regex("/health"));
     }
```

This code snippet  lists down all Spring Boot health endpoints to swagger document. I want to show only Http GET method. Does anyone have any idea about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create predicates that are based on `RequestHandler`

```java
 private Predicate<RequestHandler> onlyGets() {
    return new Predicate<RequestHandler>() {
          @Override
          public boolean apply(RequestHandler input) {
             return input.getRequestMapping()
                    .getMethodsCondition()
                    .getMethods()
                    .contains(RequestMethod.GET);
      }
    };
 }
```

and add the predicate in your api selector for your docket

```java
 //....
 new Docket().select().apis(onlyGets())
 //...
```

Comment: In my case i used spring boot actuator,that will show all http method for example :PUT,OPTIONS ..etc ,i want to expose http GET only without harming other service endpoint GET method,i have another rest endpoint call aggregation service,do u have any idea?tnx

Comment: You could create your own custom predicates based on RequestHandler. Just like `onlyGets` you could create your own combining them with ands or ors e.g.  `Predicates.and(springEndpoints(), onlyGets())`

Answer (score 1):

Currently `input.getRequestMapping()` method is deprecated, and it's in RequestHandler just for legay purposes. Instead of this, you can use:

```
 private Predicate<RequestHandler> onlyGets() {
    return new Predicate<RequestHandler>() {
          @Override
          public boolean apply(RequestHandler input) {
             return input.supportedMethods()
                    .contains(RequestMethod.GET);
      }
    };
 }
```